# Why isn't HEVC (H.265) used by smart phone apps?

Tags: compression, video-streaming, codec, hevc, h.265

I understand that there is the issue of royalty for H.265/HEVC codec but presumably that money would be paid by the smartphone manufacturer like Qualcomm for the Snapdragon. If so, why wouldn't apps like Facebook, WhatsApp, Snap use HEVC and save bandwidth, storage and other costs?

I am thinking about video chat where they just need to change the app to use the underlying hardware video encoder and decoders available on many newer chipset.

Answer (score 2):

First, Facebook allows MP4 H.265 video **uploads**. I tested a file today and it successfully posted to my timeline, although Facebook transcoded it to H.264 for **delivery**.

H.265 requires an investment by Facebook for hardware, software, and general maintenance/support. But my guess as to why they deliver in H.264 is that, until there are enough user devices with H.265 hardware support that can decode the video, it's probably not worth it yet.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking less about uploads but more about when I use WhatsApp to do a video call? Or when I use Instagram or Facebook to record the video - then a transcode is not required, correct?
Also, apps try to take advantages of underlying hardware even if not all phones support the same features. e.g., better camera/higher res is handled so I assume that if both both phones support H.265 then WhatsApp can use it more effectively?